# Split array into smaller arrays depending on when a value changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

There are several other question like this, but for all this question the sort key is known.

So here is my problem.
Consider this test class:

```
class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.value1 = val1;
        this.value2 = val2;
        this.value3 = val3;
    }
```

and here is a compare function

```
function compare(a,b){
    if(a.value3 < b.value3){
        return -1;
    if(a.value3 > b.value3){
        return 1;
    return 0
}
```

So when i have an `array of Test's` f.e. with `size 50`
I would sort this array like this.

```
arrayOfTest.sort(compare)
```

which will return my array sorted by `value3`. Now i want to split up this big array into several smaller ones, depending on WHEN value3 changes.
So for example:

```
arrayOfTest=[a = Test(value3 = 3),b = Test(value3 = 3),c = Test(value3 = 4)]
```

should be split into

```
array1 = [a = Test(value3 = 3),b = Test(value3 = 3)]
```

and

```
array3 = [c = Test(value3 = 4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to achieve your goal in a single pass (without having to sort first) would be to group by a given key, as in the following snippet:

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
// groupBy(arrayOfTest, 'value3')
```